# bootswatch templates missing in odoo 9

Tags: templates, themes, odoo, bootswatch, odoo-website

I have installed the new odoo 8 beta, both from the nightly DEB's on ubuntu 15.04, as on windows 10 with the windows EXE.

I remember that odoo 8 had several  free bootswatch templates installed from which you can choose in the web builder (spacelab, amelia, cerullian, etc). I can not find that option either. There is no choice of free themes offered.

BUT I digged into odoo9, and I see that the files for these free bootswatch themes are installed:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/amelia

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/cerulean

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/cosmo

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/cyborg

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/flatly

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/journal

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/readable

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/simplex

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/slate

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/spacelab

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/theme_bootswatch/static/src/less/united

How can I enable these themes?

Answer (score 0):

You should try following:

```
sudo npm install -g less
```

or

```
apt-get install node-less
```